# Rails form_for not accepting parameters for newly migrated columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I just migrated columns `soundcloud_url` and `image_url` to my `posts` table.  I'm trying to add soundcloud_url and image_url as fields (to submit and create a new post) in _form.html.erb, but everytime I try to submit, I get told that soundcloud_url and image_url can't be blank.  But they're not, what am I doing wrong here?

post.rb

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates_presence_of :body, :title, :soundcloud_url, :image_url
    end
```

_form.html.erb

```
      <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :title %><br>
       <%= f.text_field :title, :size => "80" %>
      </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :body %><br>
       <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 10, :cols => 50 %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :image_url %><br>
       <%= f.text_area :image_url, :rows =>"2", :cols => "50" %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :soundcloud_url %><br>
       <%= f.text_area :soundcloud_url, :rows =>"2", :cols => "50" %>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to add these two attributes to your strong parameters, if so you should have something like the following in your `posts controller`:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:soundcloud_url, :image_url, ......)
end
```

if you don't know what are strong parameters you can see this [post](http://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-preview-strong-parameters), we use strong parameters essentially to prevent malicious users assigning values to non permitted attributes, so you should specify what are exactly columns you want the user to update via form, if you don't set `:soundcloud_url` and `:image_url` to the permitted parameters, Rails will refuse to accept their values which means your model can't find values of soundcloud_url and image_url and the result is telling you that they can't be blank.

Hope this help

Comment: where should this be?

Comment: In the controller. `strong parameters`.

Comment: if you are using Rails 4 then the answer is YES, in your controller, i will update answer